# Are the Morse inequalities sharp for 5-manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Given a compact smooth manifold $M$ denote by $b_i(M)$ the $i$-th Betti number and denote by $q_i(M)$ the minimal number of generators for $H_i(M)$. Let $f$ be a Morse function on $M$. The Morse inequalities say that the number of critical points of index $k$ equals at least $b_k(M)+q_k(M)+q_{k-1}(M)$.

If $M$ is **simply connected** one can ask whether the Morse inequality is sharp, i.e. whether exists always a Morse function such that the inequalities become an equality for every $k$. Smale showed that if $\dim(M)\geq 6$, then one can always find such $f$. By the resolution of the Poincare conjecture the Morse inequality is sharp for simply connected 3-manifolds. In the 4-dimensional setting it's a famous open problem whether the Morse inequalities are sharp. Doing some literature search I could not find anything though on the status of 5-manifolds. Is it know that the Morse inequalities are (not) sharp? Or is that an open problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Presumably you mean closed. Otherwise a non-trivial h-cobordism would not have the minimal number of critical points.

For closed simply connected manifolds, it seems to me that this is Corollary 2.2.2 of Barden (Simply Connected Five-Manifolds, Annals of Mathematics Vol. 82, No. 3 (Nov., 1965), pp. 365-385)

Comment: Thanks. Great find. Of course I meant "closed". It's a metatheorem in topology that when it comes to manifolds one always forgets at least one adjective!

Comment: @StefanFriedl Not such a hard find. Look who is standing in front of me in this photo: https://msp.org/gtm/1999/02/photos/photo02.html

Comment: Haha, very good. The photo is one of great classics of geometric topology.

Comment: the photo is fantastic

Comment: @DannyRuberman Dennis Barden?

Comment: @C.F.G Just so! There's a key in the text below the photo.

Comment: @DannyRuberman, You mean hidden row? there is no one in front of young-Danny in hidden row!

Comment: I'm not sure what the confusion is. The text below the picture identifies everyone in the picture. The "(hidden)" in the caption refers not to the row being hidden, but to Ric Litherland in the third row who is partially hidden. Dennis Barden is in the second row in front of me.